# Error executing a SQL query composed of string concatenation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am designing a SQL Server 2008 R2 query.

If I used string concatenation to insert into table, it does not work.

```
  DECLARE @s1 varchar(MAX);
  DECLARE @s2 varchar(MAX);
  DECLARE @s3 varchar(MAX);
  DECLARE @s4 varchar(MAX);

  SET @s1 = 'SELECT a.id, b.name as new_name, a.value FROM ['
  SET @s2 = '].[dbo].[table1] as a, '
  SET @s3 = 'a_temp_table as b '    -- a_temp_table is a table variable. No matter I put "@" or "#" in front of  a_temp_table, it doe snot work. 
  SET @s4 = 'WHERE a.id = b.id and a.address = b.address '

  INSERT INTO [dbo].[table2]                       **nothing is inserted** 
  EXEC(@s1 + @my_database_name + @s2 + @s3 + @s4)  **this query return nothing**
```

But, if I do not use `EXEC` and just use the query directly without any string concatenation, it works.

I need to access different databases at each iteration in a loop so I prefer string concatenation.

This is the output from "print all string "

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table2] 
   SELECT a.id, b.name as new_name, a.value 
   FROM [@my_database_name].[dbo].[table1] as a, a_temp_table as b 
   WHERE a.id = b.id and a.address = b.address
```

It works if I change it to :

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table2] 
   SELECT a.id, b.name as new_name, a.value 
   FROM [@my_database_name].[dbo].[table1] as a, @a_temp_table as b 
   WHERE a.id = b.id and a.address = b.address
```

But, in string format, I got error:

```
 Must declare the table variable "@a_temp_table".
```

Comment: what error you are getting? or just nothing is inserted?

Comment: @Darka, nothing is inserted, thx

Comment: can you also put tsql, which you run directly? Are you sure you give correct `@my_database_name`? I tried on my db and seems it works.

Comment: why not just have one concatenated string that includes the "insert into..." as well? I feel the problem may lie with doing "insert into..." followed by the "EXEC(..."

Comment: @Tanner this works fine... tested...

Comment: @Darka, I am sure "@my_database_name" is correct.

Comment: @Darka Oh ok, there's my something new for today!

Comment: Try instead of `INSERT INTO [dbo].[table2] EXEC` put `PRINT` and execute what you will get.

Comment: @Tanner, the same error even though I put "INSERT ..." into a string, thx

Comment: Compose the full string into a VARCHAR(MAX) variable *before* the `INSERT..EXEC` line and PRINT the variable, before you execute it.  Show us what the PRINT says (or just try to execute it yourself).

Comment: @RBarryYoung, the real database name really gotr printed.

Comment: So does it work if you copy and paste the printed string?

Comment: I know this isn't an answer to your question but you should consider using ANSI-92 style joins instead of the older style. "[dbo].[table1] as a
join a_temp_table as b on a.id = b.id and a.address = b.address"

Comment: Still waiting for an answer to my question above:  *What happens when you copy, paste and execute the printed string?*

Comment: @RBarryYoung, it does not work.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, the reason is that I should add "@" before 'a_temp_table' , but, when I put "@" in the string "@s3", I got error:  Must declare the table variable "@a_temp_table" .

Comment: No, you add "#" before a temp table.  You add "@" before a table *variable*.  If you are using table variables you should have both *told* us and *shown* us in the text.  This took so long to debug because you hid that from us.  Variables are local context only and cannot be see in the `EXEC('<sql-string>')` execution context.

Comment: I got error: Invalid object name '#a_temp_table'.

Comment: Does "#a_temp_table" exist?  It sure doesn't look like it from what you have shown us.  Which should mean that it never would have worked, even when you "executed the query directly".

Comment: it works if I use "@cov_ded_code_temp_table" without putting it in a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
declare @sqlToExec nvarchar(2000) 
set @sqlToExec = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[table2] ' + @s1 + @my_database_name + @s2 + @s3 + @s4 
exec sp_sqlexec @sqlToExec
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SET @insert = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[table2] '
SET @qry = 'SELECT a.id, b.name as new_name, a.value FROM ['
       + '].[dbo].[table1] as a, '
       + 'a_temp_table as b '
       + 'WHERE a.id = b.id and a.address = b.address '

EXEC(@insert + @qry)
```

If that doesn't work, run this:

```
SET @insert = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[table2] '
SET @qry = 'SELECT a.id, b.name as new_name, a.value FROM ['
       + '].[dbo].[table1] as a, '
       + 'a_temp_table as b '
       + 'WHERE a.id = b.id and a.address = b.address '

Print @insert + @qry
```

Then run the generated query to ensure it is composed how you believe it should be, Splitting the insert and select if required.

Another test would be to specify the columns within the insert to see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your latest update, the problem is how you are trying to use a table variable with dynamic SQL.

My understanding is that the table variable is declared (and populated) somewhere in your main (static) script and you want to use its contents in a dynamic query.

That will not work because, as [RBarryYoung has already told you in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24913401/error-executing-a-sql-query-composed-of-string-concatenation#comment38711593_24913401), variables (including table variables) are visible only in the scope where they are declared and not anywhere else. In particular, they are *not* visible in nested EXECUTE calls.

In contrast, [local temporary tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) *can* be used the way you want it. Therefore, replace your table variable with a temporary table and reference that temporary table in your dynamic script instead of `@a_temp_table`.